# Can I dynamically alter a XUL item's insertafter attribute?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have a XUL `menuitem` element that uses the [insertafter attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/insertafter) to position itself behind a specific context-menu item. There is one edge case for which I would like to reposition my menu item. If I dynamically alter the `insertafter` attribute using JavaScript, will the position of my item automatically reposition itself the next time the context menu is displayed? Or does `insertafter` only get applied during chrome initialization?

The documentation states:

> This value may be a comma-separated list of ids, which are scanned and
>   the first one found in the window is used.

However, in my case, both IDs that I could possible use are physically present (one or the other is simply collapsed, depending on the circumstance). As such, a comma-separated list won't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the overlay applies when the window loads - changing `insertafter` attribute after that won't do anything at all, this attribute has no special meaning then. You should use the usual DOM methods, along these lines:

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("my-element");
var insertAfter = document.getElementById("element-insert-after");
if (myElement && insertAfter)
  insertAfter.parentNode.insertBefore(myElement, insertAfter.nextSibling);
```